# How to change DataGrid style dictionary by Setter via C# in WinUI3?

Tags: c#, winui-3

I have a DataGrid (CommunityToolkit.Controls), and I need to change some default style parameters. I can do it in XAML code via Setters. But I must do it programatically via C#. Can you give some C# examples how to make GridView style Setters to me? Thanks.

Comment: Try this `Style gridViewStyle = myGridView.DefaultStyle;` and `foreach (Setter setter in gridViewStyle.Setters)` and console / debug out the setter properties to see whats available, then you could probably set them using an index instead of for-loop.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say you have an `DataGrid` named **DataGridControl**. In code-behind you can set the `Style` programmatically like this:

```cs
var customStyle = new Style(typeof(DataGrid));

if (this.DataGridContro.Style is Style baseStyle)
{
    customStyle.BasedOn = baseStyle;
}

customStyle.Setters.Add(new Setter(DataGrid.RowHeightProperty, 50));

this.DataGridControl.Style = customStyle;
```

Comment: No, I mean exactly GridView.  https://github.com/CommunityToolkit/WindowsCommunityToolkit/blob/main/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls.DataGrid/DataGrid/DataGrid.xaml#L447 This link for UWP, I think WinUI package has the same code

Comment: You mean the `DataGrid` control. I updated my answer. ;)